# How to get The Key of Selected Item in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I used Material UI Multiple Select Dropdown. This is Multiple Select Component. How can I get the key of Selected Value?

Also, I get the Selected Value Which Item is Selected, but how can I get key or id of the Selected Item?

```
export default function MultipleSelectBox() {
      const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);
      const valueSheet = useContext(ContextSheet);
    
      const handleChange = (event) => {
    
        console.log(event);
    
        const { target: { value, key }, } = event;
        setPersonName(
          // On autofill we get a stringified value.
          typeof value === 'string' ? value.split(',') : value,
        );

       //if user is select the item then it shows in console, but how to get the key ?
      console.log("getSelectedValue" , event.target.value);
    
    
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 210 }} size="small">
            <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-checkbox-label">Users</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="demo-multiple-checkbox-label"
              id="demo-multiple-checkbox"
              multiple
              value={personName}
              onChange={handleChange}
              input={<OutlinedInput label="Users" />}
              renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(', ')}
              MenuProps={MenuProps}
            >
              {valueSheet.userFullName.map((name) => {
                return (
                  <MenuItem key={name.id} value={name.FullName}>
                    <Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(name.FullName) > -1} />
                    <ListItemText primary={name.FullName} />
                  </MenuItem>
                );
              })}
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can get a second argument from the `onChange` event which is a `key` object.**

This `key` is an **object** which looks  something like this: [image]

In this object you have the **`key` prop** you wanted. (with the `.$` added to it that can be easily removed)

*(By the way, you can see in the picture that you also have the `value` in this key object, inside the `props` property.)*

**So all you need is your `handleChange`  function to accept the key argument too:**

```
const handleChange = (event, key) => {
    
    const itemKey = key.key.slice(2); //Removes the .$ from the key.
    console.log(itemKey)

    const { target: { value } } = event;
    setPersonName(
      typeof value === 'string' ? value.split(',') : value,
    );

    console.log("getSelectedValue" , event.target.value);
  };
```

That's all you need to change for this.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, trying to get `key` of a React element is not the proper way to get the `id` of an object.

Instead of the current approach, you can keep track of selected objects instead of only keeping their names in `personName` and modify the rest of the code according to this change like this:

```
export default function MultipleSelectBox() {
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);
  const valueSheet = useContext(ContextSheet);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const {
      target: { value }
    } = event;
    setPersonName(value);

    console.log(
      "mapped ids of selected values",
      value.map((s) => s.id)
    );
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 210 }} size="small">
        <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-checkbox-label">Users</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-multiple-checkbox-label"
          id="demo-multiple-checkbox"
          multiple
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<OutlinedInput label="Users" />}
          renderValue={(selected) => {
            return selected.map((s) => s.FullName).join(", ");
          }}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {valueSheet.userFullName.map((name) => {
            return (
              <MenuItem key={name.id} value={name}>
                <Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(name) > -1} />
                <ListItemText primary={name.FullName} />
              </MenuItem>
            );
          })}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-select-key-ss9rzi?file=/src/App.js) for a live working example of this solution.